# Somehow the equation shows that the vector is a zero vector even actually it is not a zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega}:= \left( \omega_{0},\omega_{1},\omega_{2} \right) ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{each element of the vector is a real number}   $$

$$  \omega_{0}+ \omega_{1}+ \omega_{2} =1   $$

$$  \Pi :=\text{3*3 real matrix}  $$

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega}= \boldsymbol{\omega} \Pi   $$

I want to determine each element of $~ \boldsymbol{\omega}  ~$

What I tried are as below.

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega} -\boldsymbol{\omega} \Pi =O $$

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega} \left( E-\Pi  \right) =O $$

$$  A:=\left( E-\Pi  \right) $$

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega}  A=O $$

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega}  A  A ^{-1}  =O \cdot A ^{-1}   $$

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega}  E = O $$

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega} =O $$

But actually $~ \boldsymbol{\omega}  ~$ is not a zero vector.

Any other more good way exists?

$\Pi=$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.6 & 0.4 &0\\
    0.3&0 & 0.7\\
    0.2&0 & 0.8\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: Oh, I didn't check it.

Comment: For a non-zero $\omega$ to exist $A$ must be singular, so it has no inverse $A^{-1}$. In that case $\omega A = O$ has infinitely many solutions, and you can choose one with $\sum \omega_i=1\,$.

Comment: Your initial equations have $\omega$ as an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1,  does your matrix agree to have that eigenvalue?

Comment: I will add the info of $\Pi$ . Please wait.

Comment: Added the concrete values of elements of $\Pi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  \boldsymbol{\omega}= \boldsymbol{\omega} \Pi   $$

Do the computations of RHS to gain the one matrix.

And you can obtain $\boldsymbol{\omega}= \alpha \left(s,t,u\right) \leftarrow\text{symbol alpha is a variable}$

Using
$$\omega_{0}+\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}=1~~,$$

You can determine the value of $\alpha~~~$ .